# EF- Result of Lambda Expression to List(of Class)

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4, lambda, entity-framework-5

I have the following class:

```
Public Class CodeList
    Public Code As String
End Class
```

I am using Entity Framework.

I have the following table in a generated class:

```
Partial Public Class ContentTable
    Public Property ID As Long
    Public Property Type As Nullable(Of Integer)
    Public Property Code As String
    Public Property Active As Nullable(Of Boolean)
End Class
```

I am using this lambda expression to `select distinct Code from ContentTable`

```
Dim db As New ModelCodeEntities
Dim result = db.ContentTables.Select(Function(m As ContentTable) m.Code).Distinct().ToList
```

I want to convert the result of this lambda to a **List(of CodeList)**

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim result As List(Of CodeList)=db.ContentTables.Select(Function(item) item.Code).Distinct().Select(Function(code) new CodeList with{.Code=code}).ToList()
```

Comment: Already tried that. I got this error: **Value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of String)' cannot be converted to 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of MvcApp.ListController.CodeList)'.**

Comment: are you sure? this part of code: Select(Function(code) new CodeList with{.Code=code}) makes convert to CodeList

Comment: Can you please check my other question? Its a query of a different form, tried to apply the solution above but didnt work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23890487/select-specific-fields-with-condition-and-convert-to-list-in-entity-framework