# Select Specific Fields With Condition And Convert to List in Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, entity-framework

This is my table structure:

```
Partial Public Class KeyTable
    Public Property KeyID As Long
    Public Property ServiceName As String
    Public Property Pricing As Nullable(Of Integer)
    Public Property Active As Nullable(Of Boolean)
    Public Property Description As String
    Public Property Created As Nullable(Of Date)
End Class
```

This is a class I have

```
  Public Class Service
        Public KeyID As Double
        Public ServiceName As String
    End Class
```

I want to select the following fields

```
Select KeyID, ServiceName from KeyTable where Created= GivenDate
```

And convert the results to **List (Of Service)**

Here's what I tried so far:

```
Using db As New ServicesEntities()    
 Dim x = (From e1 In db.KeyTables Where e1.Created = sc Select e1.KeyID,e1.ServiceName).ToList() 
End Using
```

Comment: Take a look at the _Where_ extension method, the _Select_ extension method and the _ToList_ extension method.  There are many, many hits on Google for querying with Entity Framework -- even on the entity framework site.  Please show what you have already tried.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway I am aware of that. Ive tried many queries of which the mentioned above worked (check edit). No luck converting it to a List (of Service) though.

Comment: Try the following with your code for the Select method: `Select New Service() With { .KeyID = e1.KeyID, .ServiceName = e1.ServiceName }`

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
Using _DB As New ServicesEntities()
      Dim _Services As List(Of Service) = (From e1 In _DB.KeyTables Where e1.Created = sc).ToList().ConvertAll(Function(Record) New Service With{.KeyID = Record.KeyId, ServiceName = Record.ServiceName }).ToList() 
End Using
```